# Execute bat file (sja.exe) file from php

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, cmd

Anyone here know about Job.bat from SQLyog?
I want to know, can i execute the Job.bat from php? ex : from button click or function load.

I have tried from `exec ()` php function, its working properly with (`hello.bat`) but when i change the bat name to `job.bat`, it's nothing happen.

My `hello.bat` code:

```
@ECHO off
ipconfig
```

`Job.bat` file

```
  @"SJA.exe" "before.xml" -l"job.log" -s"session.xml 

  @"SJA.exe" "job.xml" -l"job.log" -s"session.xml

  @"SJA.exe" "after.xml" -l"job.log" -s"session.xml 

  pause
```

Comment: Try removing the `pause` from your `Job.bat`

Comment: Based on the coloring of Stackoverflow you are missing a closing double quote after each `session.xml`